# How to create a route with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I am using a payment system called quickWallet and it is redirecting to the following URL on my app:

```
http://localhost:3000/payment-response?status=failed&id=1009891&billnumbers=1480072195&checksum=2fcdb781a18f795459b3f388135419eeae02dda12da05e2613eae8ce4f16e514
```

How can I handle it using FlowRouter?

This is my current route definition:

```
FlowRouter.route('/payment-response?',{

    name:'payment Response Received',
    action(){ 
        BlazeLayout.render('paymentResponse');

    }
});
```

I am getting following in my console:

> kadira_flow-router.js?hash=9cd2691…:519 There is no route for the path: /payment-response?status=failed&id=1009891&billnumbers=1480072195&checksum=2fcdb781a18f795459b3f388135419eeae02dda12da05e2613eae8ce4f16e514

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the path without using the question mark, as it is only a token that denotes the query section of the URL.

As FlowRouter's [first example](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#getting-started) shows:

```
FlowRouter.route('/blog/:postId', {
    action: function(params, queryParams) {
        console.log("Yeah! We are on the post:", params.postId);
    }
});
```

the query parameters are available as the second argument of the `action()` method.

Therefore, the code should be something like:

```
FlowRouter.route('/payment-response',{
    name: 'paymentResponseReceived',
    action(_params, queryParams){
        // render your layout with the queryParams
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy worked for me. And i can access individual parameters by  queryParams.status or queryParams.id.